# How do I ping my VM for data

Tags: soap, server, virtual-machine

Target Goal:  Be able to ping my VM which has a bunch of SOAP calls at `localhost:1337/service.asmx`

Current VM Settings:   Set to Bridged with Replicate Physical Network Connection State enabled.

Known issues:

- I cant hit the internet at all from within the VM.  test via cnn.com fails.
- I can hit localhost:1337 from within the VM
- I cant hit VM localhost from the host computer.

What sort of adjustments am I going to need to make in order to open up my VM of MS Server 2012 R2 to the network for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I set up a custom port: 1337 there was actually a firewall issue.

On the VM, set it back to NAT from Bridged (in the adapter settings)

On the Windows Virtual Machine, go into Firewall Settings.

Go into Inbound Rules.

Add New Rule for the defined port.

save it.

Now the host can access via that port the page i created.